# My button needs to be clicked twice to render the new component for the first click React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a project that fetchs data from the open Trivia api. I have developed everything already and everything seems to work fine so far. However, when I first render the app, the first time I click the button to submit my answer it calls the function, but doesn't render the new question, answer choices... In order to render I have to click to choose the answer again and click the button again. Once it has rendered after clicking the check answer button for the second time, the rest of the app works perfectly at first click. I am not completely sure what is causing this bug, could you please help me?

Here it is my code:

```
  import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Card, Button, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import axios from "axios";
import "../App.css";
import Results from "./Results";

export const createMarkup = (text) => {
  return { __html: text };
};
const QuizCategory = () => {
  const [quizData, setquizData] = useState([]);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState([]);
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState([]);
  const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);
  const [questionsData, setQuestionsData] = useState([]);
  const [questionNumber, setQuestionNumber] = useState(0);
  const [selectedAnswer, setSelectedAnswer] = useState();
  const [correctAnswer, setCorrectAnswer] = useState();
  const [score, setScore] = useState(0);
  const [prevSelectedElement, setPrevSelectedElement] = useState();
  const [quizState, setQuizState] = useState("start");
  const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState(false);
  const [rightAlert, setRightAlert] = useState(false);
  const [wrongAlert, setWrongAlert] = useState(false);
  const totalQuestion = 10;

  const fetchQuizData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10");
    setQuestionsData(data);
    console.log(data);
    setCategory(data.results[questionNumber].category);
    setQuestion(data.results[questionNumber].question);
    setCorrectAnswer(data.results[questionNumber].correct_answer);

    const formattedData = data.results.map((category) => {
      const incorrectAnswersIndexes = category.incorrect_answers.length;
      const randomIndexes = Math.random() * (incorrectAnswersIndexes - 0) + 0;
      category.incorrect_answers.splice(
        randomIndexes,
        0,
        category.correct_answer
      );
      return {
        ...category,
        answers: category.incorrect_answers,
      };
    });

    setquizData(formattedData);
    setOptions(formattedData[questionNumber].answers);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuizData();
  }, []);
  const selectAnswer = (e, answer) => {
    setSelectedAnswer(answer);
    console.log("Answer Selected:", answer);

    const optionSelected = "options-selected";
    const newSelectedElement = e.target;

    if (newSelectedElement.classList.value === optionSelected) {
      newSelectedElement.classList.replace("options-selected", "options");
      setPrevSelectedElement(newSelectedElement);
    } else if (prevSelectedElement) {
      prevSelectedElement.classList.replace("options-selected", "options");
      newSelectedElement.classList.replace("options", "options-selected");
      setPrevSelectedElement(newSelectedElement);
    } else {
      newSelectedElement.classList.replace("options", "options-selected");
      setPrevSelectedElement(newSelectedElement);
    }
  };
  const checkAnswer = () => {
    console.log(
      selectedAnswer,
      correctAnswer,
      score,
      questionNumber,
      question,
      category,
      options
    );
    if (selectedAnswer === correctAnswer && questionNumber < 10) {
      setScore(score + 1);
      setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1);
      setQuestion(questionsData.results[questionNumber].question);
      setCategory(questionsData.results[questionNumber].category);
      setOptions(quizData[questionNumber].answers);
      setSelectedAnswer();
      setCorrectAnswer(questionsData.results[questionNumber].correct_answer);
      setShowAlert(false);

      console.log("Correct", questionNumber);
    } else if (
      selectedAnswer !== undefined &&
      selectedAnswer !== correctAnswer &&
      questionNumber < 10
    ) {
      setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1);
      setQuestion(questionsData.results[questionNumber].question);
      setCategory(questionsData.results[questionNumber].category);
      setOptions(quizData[questionNumber].answers);
      setSelectedAnswer();
      setCorrectAnswer(questionsData.results[questionNumber].correct_answer);
      setShowAlert(false);

      console.log("Incorrect", questionNumber);
    } else if (
      selectedAnswer !== undefined &&
      selectedAnswer === correctAnswer &&
      questionNumber === 10
    ) {
      console.log("Ready to start again?");
      setScore(score + 1);
      setQuizState("results");
      setShowAlert(false);
    } else if (
      selectedAnswer !== undefined &&
      selectedAnswer !== correctAnswer &&
      questionNumber === 10
    ) {
      console.log("Ready to start again?");
      setShowAlert(false);
      setQuizState("results");
    } else {
      setShowAlert(true);
    }
    console.log(
      selectedAnswer,
      correctAnswer,
      score,
      questionNumber,
      question,
      category
    );
  };
  console.log(selectedAnswer);
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <div className="title-text">
          <h1 className="trivia-text">Trivia</h1>
          <h1 className="coin-text"> Coin</h1>
          <h1 className="game-text">Game</h1>
        </div>

        <Row>
          {quizState === "start" ? (
            <>
              <Card className="card-big">
                <Card.Title>
                  <div
                    className="category"
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(category)}
                  ></div>
                </Card.Title>
                <Card.Body>
                  <div className="score">
                    <p
                      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(score)}
                      className="correct-score"
                    ></p>
                    /
                    <p
                      className="total-question"
                      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(totalQuestion)}
                    ></p>
                  </div>
                  <div
                    className="question"
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(question)}
                  ></div>
                  {options.map((answer) => (
                    <div
                      onClick={(e) => selectAnswer(e, answer)}
                      key={answer}
                      value={answer}
                    >
                      <li
                        className="options"
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(answer)}
                      ></li>
                    </div>
                  ))}

                  {showAlert === true ? (
                    <>
                      <Alert
                        variant="light"
                        onClose={() => setShowAlert(false)}
                        dismissible
                      >
                        <Alert.Heading>Please choose an answer!</Alert.Heading>
                      </Alert>
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="alert-component"></div>
                  )}
                  {rightAlert === true ? (
                    <>
                      <Alert
                        variant="success"
                        onClose={() => setShowAlert(false)}
                        dismissible
                      >
                        <Alert.Heading>That's Right, Good Job!</Alert.Heading>
                      </Alert>
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="alert-component"></div>
                  )}
                  {wrongAlert === true ? (
                    <>
                      <Alert
                        variant="danger"
                        onClose={() => setShowAlert(false)}
                        dismissible
                      >
                        <Alert.Heading>
                          The Right Answer is <b>{correctAnswer}</b>. You Got
                          the Next One!
                        </Alert.Heading>
                      </Alert>
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <div className="alert-component"></div>
                  )}
                  <Button
                    className="check-btn"
                    size="large"
                    variant="outline-light"
                    onClick={() => checkAnswer()}
                  >
                    CHECK ANSWER
                  </Button>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            </>
          ) : (
            <Results
              createMarkup={createMarkup}
              score={score}
              totalQuestion={totalQuestion}
            />
          )}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default QuizCategory;
```

Comment: That is quite a lot of code, you should be able to reproduce your issue using a small example which you can share as a [mre].  First glance shows that you are mutating your state when you call `.splice()`.

Comment: Well, the button that has the bug is the Check Answer one. And as I said it only happens with the first question that I fetch. I wonder if it might be because the state is not updated right away…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

When you do the following two lines you cannot expect that the `questionNumber` has incremented by one at the time of running the second line.

```
setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1);
setQuestion(questionsData.results[questionNumber].question);
```

#### Solution 1

You can use a `useEffect` to listen to question number changes and take action accordingly.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (questionNumber >= 1 && questionNumber < 10) {
      setQuestion(questionsData.results[questionNumber].question);
      setCategory(questionsData.results[questionNumber].category);
      setOptions(quizData[questionNumber].answers);
      setSelectedAnswer();
      setCorrectAnswer(questionsData.results[questionNumber].correct_answer);
      setShowAlert(false);
    }
  }, [questionNumber]);
```

Keep only the `quesionNumber` update logic in the if-else block whenever it updates useEffect will fire always with the incremented value.

[image: Edit boring-cloud-boy8n5]

#### Solution 2

You can just increment the `questionNumber` in the consecutive lines (`questionNumber + 1` instead of  just `questionNumber`) as below.

```
setQuestionNumber(questionNumber + 1);
setQuestion(questionsData.results[questionNumber + 1].question);
setCategory(questionsData.results[questionNumber + 1].category);
setOptions(quizData[questionNumber + 1].answers);
setSelectedAnswer();
setCorrectAnswer(questionsData.results[questionNumber + 1].correct_answer);
setShowAlert(false);
```

[image: Edit friendly-firefly-n2qdog]

You need to do this in both if and else if block

Comment: @Enrique Alcacer, check this out !!

Comment: Hi @Amila Senadheera! This is awesome. The use effect fixed the problem with the button, however because I am fetching the data using useEffect, when I press the button the data retrieves new data again so it desynchronized all the data. Do you know any possible solutions to this? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Did you merge the two `useEffect` hooks? data Fetch should happen inside a `useEffect` hook with empty dependencies which means it happens only when the component mounts.

Comment: Yes, I did merge them together as I have them inside the same component...

Comment: @Enrique Alcacer, that's the issue then. You could merge them only if the dependency arrays of both of them were the same and it's not (one was empty and the other one had questionNumber). Now whenever questionNumber increases it fetches a new set of data.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That's right, the idea is to have the first set of questions display and then once it is done, I would like to refresh the data by fetching the data again

Comment: I was able to fix it. I used your first method, but instead of using useEffect I used useMemo in order to render only that part. Thank you for your help! @Amila Senadheera